# Promise All stuck after first Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

I have 5 promises waiting to be executed using Promise.All

```
GenerateWeekWorkPlan = (.....) => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {

        // Some logic 

        // retVal = ... DB Manipulation ... 

          if (retVal !== null) {             
              resolve({
                status: 200,
                msg: "Successfully created ..."
              });
            } else {              
              reject({
                status: 400,
                msg: "Failed to create ..."
              });
            }

    }

}

const promiseWeek1 = this.GenerateWeekWorkPlan(.....);
const promiseWeek2 = this.GenerateWeekWorkPlan(.....);
const promiseWeek3 = this.GenerateWeekWorkPlan(.....);
const promiseWeek4 = this.GenerateWeekWorkPlan(.....);
const promiseWeek5 = this.GenerateWeekWorkPlan(.....);

Promise.all(
      promiseWeek1,
      promiseWeek2,
      promiseWeek3,
      promiseWeek4,
      promiseWeek5
    )
      .then(success => console.log(success))
      .catch(failed => console.log(failed));
```

The code runs only the first promise and then get stuck.
Why doesn't continue to next promises (2-3-4-5) ?

**EDIT:**

```
GenerateWeekWorkPlan = (weekNumber, packageId, arrayOfTargets) => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      // Get all the raw data from Leads collection that is not Duplicated
      console.log("GenerateWeekWorkPlan ...");
      try {
        // 1. Get leads by package id and take all those which are not duplicated
        const leads1 = await Leads.find({
          Duplicate: false,
          PackageId: packageId
        })
          .lean()
          .exec(async (err, leads) => {
            // docs are plain javascript objects instead of model instances



            const oneWeekWorkPlan = arrayOfTargets.map(target => {
              return leads.map(lead => ({
                        .... 
              }));
            });

            console.log("--------Insert Many----------");
            const flatted = oneWeekWorkPlan.flat();
            console.log(flatted);

            const retVal = await WeekPlangs.insertMany(flatted);
            console.log("--------Done Insert Many----------");
            if (retVal !== null) {
              console.log("retVal" + retVal);
              resolve({
                status: 200,
                msg: "Successfully created documents"
              });
            } else {
              console.log("Nothing inside retVal" + retVal);
              reject({
                status: 400,
                msg: "Failed to create documents"
              });
            }
          });
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        reject({
          status: 400,
          msg: "Failed to create documents"
        });
      }
    });
  };
};
```

Comment: What do you by gets stuck on how do you know the first promise was resolved?

Comment: is the wrapper supposed to be async?

Comment: @dandavis: Yes ,I'm using await to get stuff from MongoDB

Comment: there's no await in the code shown though... Promises themselves aren't supposed to be `async` technically, even if they are for sure async practically.

Comment: @dandavis: You suggest removing the async from the Promise ?

Comment: i can't see enough code to say that's 100% the problem, but it seems reasonable, unless something is throwing before that point.

Comment: @dandavis: I added the code in the Edit section.Thanks

Comment: Wrapping an existing promise inside a `new Promise()` is not necessary and is considered a promise anti-pattern.  Just return the promises you already have - no need to wrap them in a new one. Beyond that, I don't understand what the question is asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Never pass an `async function` as the executor to `new Promise`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43036229/1048572)! It seems you are using it so that you can call `resolve` and `reject` from the asynchronous `exec()` callback - but really you shouldn't have used that callback in the first place. You would want to [promisify](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572) the call and `await` it, or in case of MongoDB all you would need to do is drop the callback to get back a promise. Make `GenerateWeekWorkPlan` itself the `async` function so that it returns a promise:

```
async function GenerateWeekWorkPlan(weekNumber, packageId, arrayOfTargets) {
  // Get all the raw data from Leads collection that is not Duplicated
  console.log("GenerateWeekWorkPlan ...");
  try {
    // 1. Get leads by package id and take all those which are not duplicated
    const leads = await Leads.find({
      Duplicate: false,
      PackageId: packageId
    }).lean();
    // docs are plain javascript objects instead of model instances
    const oneWeekWorkPlan = arrayOfTargets.flatMap(target => {
      return leads.map(lead => ({
        …
      }));
    });

    console.log("--------Insert Many----------");
    console.log(oneWeekWorkPlan);
    const retVal = await WeekPlangs.insertMany(oneWeekWorkPlan);
    console.log("--------Done Insert Many----------");
    if (retVal !== null) {
      console.log("retVal" + retVal);
      return {
        status: 200,
        msg: "Successfully created documents"
      };
    } else {
      console.log("Nothing inside retVal" + retVal);
      throw {
        status: 400,
        msg: "Failed to create documents"
      };
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    throw {
      status: 400,
      msg: "Failed to create documents"
    };
  }
}
```